# Не устанавливается poetry на linux

Tags: python, poetry

```
user@DESKTOP-8P6EA17:~$ curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
Retrieving Poetry metadata

# Welcome to Poetry!

This will download and install the latest version of Poetry,
a dependency and package manager for Python.

It will add the `poetry` command to Poetry's bin directory, located at:

/home/user/.local/bin

You can uninstall at any time by executing this script with the --uninstall option,
and these changes will be reverted.

Installing Poetry (1.3.1): An error occurred. Removing partial environment.
Poetry installation failed.
See /home/user/poetry-installer-error-ck33xlva.log for error logs.
```

Что с ним не так? Почему это такой проблемный инструмент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

зачем делать сложно, если

```sh
pip3 install poetry
```

от имени администратора (`root`) крайне желательно.